# How can I call a webservice from COBOL mainframe?

Tags: web-services, web, cobol, cics

How can I call a webservice from a COBOL program? I have no idea how to do this, can any one help and define steps?

Any sample code will be more hellpful.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the COBOL program running?  In CICS on z/OS?  SOAP or REST?

Comment: running in CICS

Comment: I put your topic title into Google and it came up with lots of results. What specific problem do you have that is not answered there?

Answer (score 6):

CICS Transaction Server documentation is available [here.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts)  Select your version and release of CICS.

Invoking a REST web service from CICS COBOL can be done via the `WEB OPEN`, `WEB CONVERSE`, and `WEB CLOSE` application programming interfaces.    The APIs are documented in the Reference section.

Invoking a SOAP web service from CICS COBOL requires some setup work, often via the CICS Web Services Assistant provided with CICS (search on DFHWS2LS) however your shop may make use of IBM's CICS Explorer or there are third-party tools your shop may have decided to acquire for this purpose.

The capability to invoke REST and SOAP web services has existed since at least 2005 when CICS Transaction Server 3.1 was made generally available.

In either case, you are best served by talking to your CICS support staff about what is allowed in your shop and how they and your security staff want to proceed.  As these capabilities have existed for quite some time now, most shops likely have some policies and procedures in place governing their use.